# Printing square instead of parallelogram

Tags: c, while-loop

I'm now trying to print a parallelogram only with while loop. I wrote some code but It's printing square instead of parallelogram. I'm used to do these things with for loops but doing it with while is unusual for me.

```
while (x < k)
{

  while (y < k)
  {

    printf(" *  ");
    y++;

  }

  x++;
  printf("  \n  ");
  y = 0;

}
```

When I enter k = 4, output is:

```
*    *    *    *
    *    *    *    *
    *    *    *    *
    *    *    *    *
```

I want it to be :

```
*    *    *    *
    *    *    *    *
        *    *    *    *
             *    *    *    *
```

Comment: Unless you can show us your correct solution using a for-loop, I doubt that your lack of familiarity with `while` compared to `for` is the cause of your problem - but rather your *excuse*. In C for-loop of the form `for( a; b; c ){ d } ;` is exactly equivalent to `a; while(b){ d; c }`, so translating a for-loop solution to a while loop solution is trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is print N tabulations according to your number of line.
Try this:

```
while (x < k)
{

  while (y < k)
  {

    printf(" *  ");
    y++;

  }

  x++;
  printf("  \n");
  y = 0;
  while (y < x)
  {
      printf("\t");
      y++;
  }
  y = 0;
}
```

Comment: It prints first 4 stars next to window and others with tabs. Making last ones square again.

Comment: @Halim i corrected it, sorry, you're supposed to print X tabulations, according to x.

Comment: @HalilM you're welcome , dont forget to close your question if everything is ok for you